# How to center align <li> items when it goes to 2nd line?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a Un-ordered list using single `<ul> .... </ul>`

How to align 2nd line in center?

[image]

I created JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/JWHQQ/ to test

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To align `<ul>` element in the center, set left and right margins to `auto`:

```
ul{ text-align:center;width:450px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}
li{ float:left;padding:15px}
```

To align both lines of `<li>` to center, use `display: inline` as [suggested by domanokz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006262/how-to-center-align-li-items-when-it-goes-to-2nd-line/7006306#7006306). But in this case `<li>` lose their margins and paddings. To keep them, set `display` to `inline-block`:

```
ul{ text-align:center;width:450px;}
li{ display:inline-block;padding:15px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the lost of margin and padding. However, I'm afraid that inline-block will not work correctly in IE5 and IE6 as stated in this article: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @domanokz Yes, that's true. But there's no other way to keep margins, however, paddings should be preserved on inline elements, yet my quick tests in Firefox show that only `padding-left` and `padding-right` are applied to `<li>` with `display: inline`. In this case `line-height` property on `<ul>` could be used to control how close the two lines are. Although I'm not sure if it works correct in IE5 and IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `li`'s inline... You don't have to set the `float:left`

```
ul{ text-align:center;width:450px}
li{ display:inline;padding:15px}
```

Comment: But I also want to use `Float`

Comment: I believe that is not possible. `float:left` will make them aligned to left. Why do you want them float anyway?

Answer (score 1):

does this do the trick?

http://jsfiddle.net/JWHQQ/5/

I made the li inline elements instead of making them float left.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the best solution.

```
ul{ text-align:center;width:450px magin:0 auto}<br>
li{ display:inline;padding:15px}
```